# Data import error handling using CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, import

I'm using CLI command `sf data import tree` to import data based on a JSON plan into Salesforce org. If the data import gets an error for any record, then the whole load fails. Is it possible to somehow skip the failed records and import those without errors?